# How to set the accessibility hint (iOS/VoiceOver) in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, voiceover

On iOS accessibility hint and label are different, so I'm wondering if React Native also exposes the accessibility hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Accessibility hint is now available as of the React Native 0.57 release. Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/08/13/react-native-accessibility-updates

Based on their [accessibility documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html), it doesn't look like they expose a way to set the accessibility hint.

Although there does seem to be a pull request to add that feature: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18093